# Extract characters after certain other characters Excel

Tags: excel

I have a list of cells that looks more or less like this:

- ARB:d.p.1-4-12
- ANT:d.p.1-12-1
- D:d.p.1-1-1
- ONN:d.p.4-2-12

I'm trying to figure out how I can extract certain key elements from these strings.
If we take the first entry as example, this is what I want to extract and display in another cell:

```
ARB d 1
```

I want all characters before ":", then the first character after ":" and the first number (or ONE character before the first "-").

I've played around with TRIM, LEFT/RIGHT and FIND - but can't figure out how to get only ONE character after/before a certain character. This is what I've tried, but dont know how to limit the output to only ONE character:

```
TRIM(LEFT(E5;FIND(":";E5)-1))
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers or tips :-)

**Update, got it working:**

I ended up using this code, which was tweaked after jiggle's suggestion.

```
=TRIM(LEFT(E2;FIND(":";E2)-1)) & RIGHT(MID(E2;FIND(":";E2);2);1) & RIGHT(MID(E2;FIND("p.";E2);3);1)
```

This gave me the following output:
ARBd1

Now I just need to add some separators and im all good to go. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: `MID` function should help you: [link](http://office.microsoft.com/ru-ru/excel-help/HA102838074.aspx)

Comment: This is a typical application of regular expressions as search tool. No idea if spread sheet applications support 'em, though. Maybe there is an extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find the first part : `=LEFT(E5,FIND(":",E5)-1)`

Find the second part: `=MID(E5,FIND(":",E5)+1,1)`

= MID ( Text , Start_num , Num_chars )

so here we're starting at the character after the ":", by adding 1 to the FIND

and taking 1 character, at the end

Find the last part: `=MID(E5,FIND("-",E5)-1,1)`

doing a similar thing to the second part, but now starting at the character before the "-" by subtracting 1 from where we found it, and again taking just 1 character

To combine them all together, just use the concatenation character "&" and space:

`=LEFT(E5,FIND(":",E5)-1)&" "&MID(E5,FIND(":",E5)+1,1) & " " & MID(E5,FIND("-",E5)-1,1)`

EDITED to replace commas with semi colons (for different cultures):

```
=LEFT(E5;FIND(":";E5)-1)&" "&MID(E5;FIND(":";E5)+1;1) & " " & MID(E5;FIND("-";E5)-1;1)
```

Comment: Hi, this isn't working. First part is OK, second part and third part gives me the error "Youve entered too few arguments for this function".

So I reworked that part to:
    =MID(E5;FIND(":";E5);2) .... This gives me ":d" , which is OK but not ideal. Any thoughts?

Comment: mmm sorry, works fine for me with UK excel settings, looks like yours needs semi-colons insteads of commas.  Try this =MID(E5;FIND(":";E5)+1;1)

Comment: I fixed it on my own, by tweaking the code you helped me out with! :-) I ended up using this: =TRIM(LEFT(E2;FIND(":";E2)-1)) & RIGHT(MID(E2;FIND(":";E2);2);1) & RIGHT(MID(E2;FIND("p.";E2);3);1). Thats a lot of excel code :F Thanks dude!

Comment: Great! You're welcome Simen - Though you don't need that RIGHT in there, as you are taking 2 chars using the MID, then taking the second character by using RIGHT, so if you change RIGHT(MID(E2;FIND(":";E2);2);1)  to MID(E2;FIND(":";E2)+1;1), you will get the same result - it's the +1 in the "FIND(":";E2)+1" that says 'from the first character after ":"'.....try this full expression that I've changed to use semi-colons instead of commas :  =LEFT(E5;FIND(":";E5)-1)&" "&MID(E5;FIND(":";E5)+1;1) & " " & MID(E5;FIND("-";E5)-1;1)